# Convert array object in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Need to convert array objects given below

```
[{ key:"url", value:"new" },{ key:"page", value:1 }]  // after (need to convert like this)
{ url:"new", page:1 }  // before
```

Comment: Please, do some research before asking.

Comment: Are all "before" objects structured as shown? Likewise with the "after" objects? BTW, this is not really an angular question.

Comment: I want conversion vice versa

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) :

```js
const array = [];

Object.entries({ url: "new", page: 1 }).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  array.push({ key, value })
})

console.log(array)
```

Comment: { url:"new", page:1 }

Need to convert like below [{ key:"url", value:"new" },{ key:"page", value:1 }]

Comment: it's the purpose of the code sample. see it in action here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-gasfg5?devtoolsheight=60